# Class Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider not found

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to use Moltin Cart in my Laravel 4 app.

I installed Moltin Cart through composer, then added the Service Provider `('Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider')` and added the  aliases `('Cart' => 'Moltin\Cart\Facade')`.

Now i am getting the laravel 4 error - `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Class 'Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider' not found`.

Can someone please give me some advise on how or where to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done a autoload dump to rebuild your class map?

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thanks Warspite. I just ran it and it no longer shows the error. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure that out.

Comment: Np... don't forget to check the answer as solved so it shows up as resolved for future SO users.  Also you can add the dump autoload into your composer.json as a post update command so yiu never have to run it manually when you add packages.  Check the composer docs for `post-update`

Comment: I tried to vote up this answer but I need 15 rep pts first. But this was the correct answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

add this line in composer.json
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
 "prefer-stable": true,

and commond used to update as follow
$composer require "moltin/laravel-cart" --prefer-dist